# How to alter a column type which contains data using the Alembic API and Oracle Database?

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

The Alembic API has an `alter_column` method on the migration context object (https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.alter_column).  However, when I tried to alter a column type of a column that contains data Oracle responded with "ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype".

How should I use the Alembic API in order to alter a column type, which contains data?

E.g., change the column type from date to varchar.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using oracle 11g & onward then you can go for [virtual column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)
2. create new column with required datatype, update it's data with old column's data, delete old column, rename new column with old column name